# Define Filter web part query order for List view

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, list-view-threshold

I have added one list view on SharePoint page. It has several filter web parts added to it. This list has huge data. So I need to define the order for the filter web part so that Indexed column filter(or filter which gives fewer results) should be passed first.

> Eg: First Email then Approval status

If List view is filtered with Approval status column first then I would get more than threshold values.

I tried several different orders of connecting filters to list view. But it's not working